# Dictionary how can i change values to string

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
dict = {18: ["Allison", "Janette"], 20: ["David", "Erik", "Zack"], 25: ["Grace"]}
```

Change to this

```
dict = {18: "Allison and Janette", 20: "David and Erik and Zack", 25: "Grace"}
```

Comment: Use `" and ".join()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for key in dict.keys():
    dict[key] = " and ".join(dict[key])
```

Also dont use dict as a variable name because its a name for a built in function

Answer (score 0):

Using dict comprehension:

```
print ({ k:' and '.join(v) for k,v in dct.items() })
```

Btw, don't call your `dict` dict, which is a reserved name for the corresponding object type.